# "Cannot open the disk...Failed to lock the file" with VMware VM

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine, vmware

I run openSUSE 10.2 VM on VMware on a Windows Vista host. Yesterday I run VMware and another VM but both couldn't run, and I ended both tasks to solve it. But now I can open VMware without any problem and run the other OS VM but not the openSUSE VM. The error is:

> Cannot open the disk
>   'C:\Users\hamide\Documents\Virtual
>   Machines\SUSE Linux 2\SUSE Linux
>   2-000003.vmdk' or one of the snapshot disks it depends on.
>   Reason: Failed to lock the file.

I don't have any backups.

Comment: Check out http://sharethelearning.blogspot.com/2008/02/vmware-virtual-machine-failed-to-lock.html It is a little old but I am sure if you google that error you will find something more up to date.

Comment: Ask this on superuser.com .

Comment: Can you just copy the vmdk and re-attach the copy to your instance?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to remove or rename the `.lck` file (as posted in the link in the comment to the question, answered here for posterity). Search for [vmware KB](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003857) "Investigating hosted virtual machine lock files".